# Post-order/Pre-order Traversal of Binary Tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree, postorder

I have a pre-order traversal function that looks like this:

```
void listInPreOrder(node* hd){
if(hd != NULL) {
        printf("%d, ", hd->value);
        listInPreOrder(hd->left);
        listInPreOrder(hd->right);
    }
}
```

That in fact works, but I thought that making it post order would be as simple as this

```
void listInPostOrder(node* hd){
if(hd != NULL) {
        listInPreOrder(hd->left);
        listInPreOrder(hd->right);
        printf("%d, ", hd->value);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it does not work so well. I'm wondering how to fix this, maybe I'm doing something simple wrong. Or maybe it's completely wrong.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk, you didn't change the recursive calls...

Comment: The code is the same on both, just transposed the print line to the bottom. Also try post the other code as well, as it is hard to determin the fault just by function calls. E.g. how do you construct the node...

Comment: Yes that is how it's supposed to be. I thought that that was how post-order traversal is coded recursively. That is what I'm wondering about. The function calls are correct so far as I can see. I'm wondering if the function for post-order is faulty or not.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk. the idea in post-order traversal is that you traverse the sub-trees in post order as well. See WhosCraigs answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about you change this:

```
void listInPostOrder(node* hd){
if(hd != NULL) {
        listInPreOrder(hd->left);  // PRE order ???
        listInPreOrder(hd->right); // PRE order ???
        printf("%d, ", hd->value);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
void listInPostOrder(node* hd){
if(hd != NULL) {
        listInPostOrder(hd->left);
        listInPostOrder(hd->right);
        printf("%d, ", hd->value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Derp, yeah.. I feel like an idiot whenever I ask a question like so. But I spent 10 minutes trying to understand why without even reading the method calls in the function.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk You would (probably not) be shocked how often this happens in new recursion implementations of of BST traversals. I literally did this *in an answer to a different question* a couple days ago, so I'm rather intimate with that "derp" feeling.